# Dropzone used in codeigniter project is not working on the live server

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

**my view looks:**

```
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('Admin/addBrandsProcess'); ?>" class="dropzone" >

    </form>
```

**my Controller looks:**

```
public function addBrandsProcess() 
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT width, height FROM brandimage');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $width= $row->width;
        $height= $row->height;    
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES)) 
    {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $targetPath = getcwd() . './assets/images/brand/';
        $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $targetPath . $fileName ;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = $width;
        $config['height'] = $height;
        $config['quality'] = '100%';

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();            
        $this->db->insert('brands',array('image' => $fileName));
    }
}
```

This code working well in local server, but not in live server. Here my problem is image is not uploaded to the target folder. Here the image name is get saved in the table **brands**. But image is not uploaded in the target path  **$targetPath = getcwd() . './assets/images/brand/';**.

How can I solve this problem. What all changes have to make.

Comment: better to check if you are using CI `base_url` function if you are targeting path directory.

Comment: $targetPath =  base_url() . './assets/images/brand/'; I checked by using this but its not working.

Comment: Does the target path exist on your live server? Also do all of the folders have proper permissions? Like read and write privileges.

Comment: if your using CI3 make sure you have not left the config base url blank.

Comment: both folder permissions & config base url is fine

Comment: `$targetPath = base_url('/assets/images/brand/')`; try this one

Comment: Try to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` attribute. your form should like this `<form action="<?php echo site_url('Admin/addBrandsProcess'); ?>" class="dropzone"  enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Please check your uploaded directory **permission**. if you are running your code on linux/centos/ubuntu then it might be permission issue.

Comment: problem solved:  $targetPath = getcwd() . './assets/images/brand/'; to  $targetPath = getcwd() . '/assets/images/brand/';

Comment: thank u all for your valuable time :)